# Get all XHR Requests of a Site in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

I want to make a program in python that prints out all the xhr requests of a site.

I can do this with the inspect tool, by going to Network -> XHR, but I would like to run a code that does this.

[image]

The code should give out a dictionary with a key of name, and a value of a dictionary with the corresponding Request URL, Request METHOD, content-type, and remote address.

For Example:

```py
aDict = {'randomfile.js?_=1581185731016': {'url': 'https://softwaresat.netlify.com/randomfile.js?_=1581185731016', 'method': 'GET', 'address': '104.248.60.43:443'}}
```

Comment: as far as I know you can't do this with `requests` since these requests are made in the JS of the page, you will probably need to use other tools to capture this

Comment: what tools, exactly @aws_apprentice

Comment: look [here](http://toddhayton.com/2015/03/11/scraping-ajax-pages-with-python/) and [here](https://www.codementor.io/@codementorteam/how-to-scrape-an-ajax-website-using-python-qw8fuitvi)

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the selenium-wire python module for getting all the xhr calls of a website which helped me for my projects.

Install module
`pip install selenium-wire`

Sample code to get xhr requests for google.com

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Go to the Google home page
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url
        )
```